# How can I reach the chest at the top of the Towers of Twin Dragons?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

At the top of the Towers of Twin Dragons, there's a pair of chests at the very top.

[image: map]
*at the marked spot*

After gaining **Invert**, I was able to get the first. But the second one I can't see a way to reach it.

[image: the chest can be seen at the right]
*look to the far right underneath the spikes*

So far I haven't seen any breakable walls and this area appears to be completely inaccessible.

**How do I get to this chest?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to go near the **left** exit at the bottom of this zone ;

[image: map]

Then use **Invert**

[image: map]

I hope it helped you :)

Good luck.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid I missed something like that. I'll check it out when I get the chance, I'm sure you're correct.

Comment: Sure :)
I tried to figure out how to get this chest too, then I randomly saw your post and decided to give it a last try :D 
Found it few minutes later.

Comment: Ok, so the Aegis Armor inside the chest is also needed for progression.